# Animation doesnt work - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

Everytime I try to implement an animation in my `viewDidLoad`, it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: 
[.repeat,.autoreverse], animations: {

        self.viewpost.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 360)

    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: What does it do? What doesn't it do? What's the error? How are you running it?

Comment: Your view controller isn't on screen when `viewDidLoad` is called

Comment: Few things you could try:
1, place your code in didAppear
2, try some small angle first, like 90 degree,
3, The angle, in radians plz.

Comment: Placing in the didAppear worked, thanks guys !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your animation to ViewDidAppear.

In ViewDidLoad the ViewController will load but is not shown yet. Because of that the animations wont show or may partially show if the animation is longer than the time for the View Controller to Appear after loading.

In ViewDidAppear the ViewController is on the screen so your animations will fully take place

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ElTomato Please if you can explain, why its not correct?

Comment: One could partially see the animation unless it really takes the app more than 2 seconds to show the content of the view controller.

Comment: The DidAppear takes a lot more time than DidLoad (especially if it is the first view controller to be presented in the app). @ElTomato I updated my answer accordingly. :)